# json output to file readable again in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, transfer

I want to be able to transfer a php array from one server to another via ftp in the form of a file.

The receiving server needs to be able to open the said file and read its contents and use the array provided.

I've thought about going about this two ways, either writing a php file from server 1 with php code of an array then simply loading this file on server 2. However writing the said file is getting tricky when the depth of the array is unknown.

So I though about writing the array to the file json encoded but I don't know how the second server could open and read the said data.

Could I simply do:

```
$jsonArray= json_encode($masterArray);
$fh = fopen('thefile.txt' , 'w');
fwrite($fh, $thePHPfile);
fclose($fh);
```

Then on the other server open the data into a variable:

```
$data = json_decode( include('thefile.txt') );
```

Has anyone had any experience of this before?

Comment: You say you wanna do this by FTP. How about setting up a FTP connection first?

Comment: ftp connections, writing the file... etc etc is not the problem. I just don't know what is the best solution to sending an array from one server to another and having the recieving server parse the said array...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For first server, connect to second server by FTP and put that file contents into a file

```
$jsonArray = json_encode($masterArray);
$stream    = stream_context_create(array('ftp' => array('overwrite' => true))); 
file_put_contents('ftp://user:pass@host/folder/thefile.txt', $jsonArray, 0, $stream);
```

use `file_get_contents()` for second server:

```
$data = json_decode( file_get_contents('/path/to/folder/thefile.txt') );
```

Comment: you do kill me! so an easy way! I was still using ftp_* family

Answer (score 1):

If you're only going to be interested in reading the file using PHP, have you thought about using `serialize()` and `unserialize()`?

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

It's also *probably* faster than `json_encode()` / `json_decode()` (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php#103761).

Answer (score 0):

The PHP Function that your looking for is : **file_get_contents**

```
$masterArray = array('Test','Test2','Test3');
$jsonArray= json_encode($masterArray);
$fh = fopen('thefile.txt' , 'w');
fwrite($fh, $jsonArray);
fclose($fh);
```

Then on the other server:

```
$masterArray = json_decode( file_get_contents('thefile.txt') );
var_dump($masterArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

To "transfer" the array between servers, using a file as medium, you found a nice solution by using `json_encode` and `json_decode`. The `serialize` and `unserialize` functions would perform the same goal nicely.

```
$my_array = array('contents', 'et cetera');

$serialized = serialize($my_array);
$json_encoded = json_encode($my_array);

// here you send the file to the other server, (you said you know how to do)
// for example:
file_put_contents($serialized_destination, $serialized);
file_put_contents($json_encoded_destination, $json_encoded);
```

In the receiving server, you just need to read the file contents and apply the corresponding "parse" function:

```
$serialized = file_get_contents($serialized_destination);
$json_encoded = file_get_contents($json_encoded_destination);

$my_array1 = unserialize($serialized);
$my_array2 = json_decode($json_encoded);
```